A boy who becomes a sorcerer only when he falls asleep
I remember reading this book around 2003 when I was in middle school. I believe it was a bit older than that, however. I'm sure it was about a boy who becomes a sorcerer when he falls asleep and dreams.
He is taught that whatever magic he uses must have a counterbalance for it to work. If he heals something another thing will lose its health.

The dreaming part of this story-id made me think of The Lives of Christopher Chant, but I don't recall anything about balance in the magic system.

Pawn's Dream by Eric S. Nylund? It's a young man, not a boy; and when he's asleep he dreams about another world. Turns out it's actually real, and his family is prominent there. The magic works on polarities (light/dark, heat/cold, fire/water  etc) He decides to use Life/death, which no-one has thought of doing before.
